# How to redirect output in different files in python

Tags: python, input, output

I am using the  python script that takes two input files (goodProteins.fasta and list.txt) 
and save result in gene.fasta output files.

```
fasta_file = "goodProteins.fasta" # First input 
wanted_file = "list.txt" # Second input
result_file = "result.txt" # Output fasta file

wanted = set()
with open(wanted_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line != "":
            wanted.add(line)

fasta_sequences = SeqIO.parse(open(fasta_file),'fasta')
with open(result_file, "w") as f:
    for seq in fasta_sequences:
        if seq.id in wanted:
            SeqIO.write([seq], f, "fasta")
```

But now I have several list files (list1.txt, list100.txt etc) that are present in the subdirectory 'outfile'
within the current directory. I want to take each list file one at a time, proceed through the script and generates the corresponding output files
(gene1.fasta, gene100.fasta) and saved them in a separate sub directory 'result'.

Any help??

Comment: Is there an equal number of the first input file and the second input file?

Comment: no.. there is only one goodProteins.fasta files, but list files (which are in outfile subfolder) are many

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple

```
def process(wanted_file, result_file):
    fasta_file = "goodProteins.fasta" # First input 

    wanted = set()
    with open(wanted_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line != "":
                wanted.add(line)

    fasta_sequences = SeqIO.parse(open(fasta_file),'fasta')
    with open(result_file, "w") as f:
        for seq in fasta_sequences:
            if seq.id in wanted:
                SeqIO.write([seq], f, "fasta")

for i in range(100):
    wanted_file = "list" + str(i) + ".txt"
    result_file = "gene" + str(i) + ".txt"
    process(wanted_file, result_file)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. your script works well if the number of my list file is continuous incremental no. (eg. list1.txt, list2.txt etc) .. but actually my list file numbers are large and  do not follow any specific pattern (such as list3348.txt, list2781.txt etc).. plz suggest ..

Comment: import os; for (i, wanted_file) in enumerate(os.listdir("path/to/lists/folder")):process(wanted_file, "gene" + str(i) + ".txt"